# Saucer pilot uses mind control. Short story from 50's

Tags: story-identification

Need title of small anthology of scifi short stories published in the early or mid 50's one of flying saucer pilot who used thought control to fly.

What was interesting is that the author (who I can no longer remember) was in the armed services and of high rank during the late 40's and died in a mysterious accident shortly after book was published. Does anyone recall title or other details?

Comment: Interesting. You might want to check out [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/21267) to see if it helps jog your memory.

Comment: I was going to say Richard Sharpe Shaver, infamous for his conspiracy theories, but it looks like he didn't die until 1975.